# JBoss AS 4.2 Overview tab in Eclipse Luna EE SR2

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss-tools

This is probably trivial question but I can't find solution to it. I past few days I installed several times Luna EE R with JBoss AS Tools (while it was still beta),

[image]

and I had automatically (or I think it was automatically) - after configuration - JBoss Overview tab opened, and in Project Explorer I had Servers -> JBoss AS 4.2 server shown.

Now, with new installation, Eclipse Luna EE SR2, and JBossAS Tools stable release, I don't have it, and I can't find where or how to turn it on. Othervwise it works OK (I can run or debug project). Now there are some quute important settings in that Overrview tab so my questions are:

1. How to open JBoss AS 4.2 Overview tab
2. How to show JBoss server in Project Explorer
3. Why my project "MC_trunk" it is not listed in debug Configuration, Remote Java Application, and how to get that?

[image]

Probably this is just one or two check boxes which I miss, but I opened both versions of eclipse I just find how to get those views.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftmetasrv.html). Apparently I what I had to do was:

Window -> Show View -> Servers, open Servers tab, right click on JBoss AS 4.2 -> Properties -> Switch Location -> Location: [workspace metadata] -> Location: /Servers/JBoss AS 4.2.server -> Apply -> OK

Comment: I'm wondering why you want the metadata stored in a workspace project instead of just in the default location ?

it provides no specific feature/difference doing that except taking up more ui space in project explorer.